# entryUUID vs DN

Tags: php, ldap

When you need to refer to a precise ldap entry what do you prefer to use entryUUID or DN?

I have a grid. every item is a ldap entry. Every row in the grid has a checkbox which contains the item's ID. It could be entryUUID or DN. Which one would you use?

I would like to use entryUUID just to avoid situations like ["new DirectoryEntry(distinguishedName as string)" doesn't work when DN contains a "/"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530247/new-directoryentrydistinguishedname-as-string-doesnt-work-when-dn-contains-a) and to hook easily the selected item even if the user changes the CN. 
Of course using entryUUID means to pay attention in ldap backups and restores.

Any usefull tip?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User entryUUID and slapcat for backing up your data.
slapcat command export also entryUUID attribute.